# Looking for command line values for an older (9.22 beta) 7zip

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

Better yet, is there a help file for the older 7zip utility?

I want to test some PW recovery tools (build encrypted zip w/ known PW).  This is probably trivial but starting from a 7zip.exe that has no GUI how do I specify AES256?  and / or what values does the -t switch take?  What are the 'types' allowed?
Thanks

Comment: There is help info at this site    https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm